# Нереализованные или не реализованные?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

> ...но из-за низкой инвестиционной привлекательности остаются не реализованными.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[РЕАЛИЗОВАННЫЙ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1007002/%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%90%D0%9B%D0%98%D0%97%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%99) (книжн.). Прич. страд. прош. вр. от *реализовать*.

С действительными и полными страдательными причастиями (если при них нет зависимых слов и противопоставления) НЕ пишется слитно.
[НЕ с причастиями](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.56)

**...но из-за низкой инвестиционной привлекательности остаются нереализованными.**

*Время идет, мы продолжаем бежать вперед, а наши мечты так и **остаются нереализованными**, отложенными на потом* (Г. Кибардин).
*Не менее важной остается проблема коррумпированности российских чиновников, из-за которой многие проекты **остаются нереализованными...*** (А. Мудрак)

Вот примеры раздельного написания:
*На сегодня эта идея остаётся пока что никем не реализованной, хотя ей активно занимаются две западные корпорации* (India Daily).
*В теории коммунизм – это пока еще никем не реализованный общественный строй, при котором упраздняется частная собственность...* (Е. Малевич)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, нужно писать слитно. Здесь утверждается нереализованность и нет противопоставления (например: не реализованные, а потерянные).

В Нацкопрусе найдено 12 вхождений типа "оставаться нереализованным" (со слитным написанием), например:

> Тогда все заложенные в боевой комплекс возможности остаются нереализованными. [Владимир Бабич. МИГи в локальных войнах (из книги «Российское оружие: война и мир») (1997)]

Не найдено ни одного вхождение с раздельным написанием (*оставаться не реализованным*).